# Остановить анимацию на последнем кадре

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d

Добрый вечер.

```
 brazgi_ani_ani = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:brazgi_ani_mas delay:0.1f];
    self.brazgi_create_ani = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:brazgi_ani_ani]];
```

Запускаю анимацию, используя атлас. Столкнулся с проблемой. Каким образом я могу остановить ее на последнем кадре? А так же на нужном мне кадре? Например, на 10-м.

Спасибо.